# Minimizing the Hypotenuse by Minimizing Area

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am teaching a calculus class and gave the students this standard problem: Suppose that a $10$ foot wall is $4$ feet from the side of a building.  What is the smallest ladder that will let you get over the wall and reach the building?

The problem amounts to minimizing the hypotenuse (length of ladder) of a right triangle.  My student asked if this is the same problem as minimizing the area of the triangle.  If $a$ and $b$ represent the legs of the triangle and $c$ is the hypotenuse, then the area can be written as
$$
A = \frac{1}{2}a\sqrt{c^2 - a^2}.
$$
Since area is not just a function of $c$, my gut feeling is that the area of the triangle and the hypotenuse can't be related in the correct way.  Is that true?  Or, does minimizing area work?

Comment: If we fix the area and make the height over the hypothenuse smaller and smaller, the hypothenuse gets bigger and bigger. So, minimizing the area cannot be enough to minimize the hypothenuse.

Comment: If by "height over the hypotenuse smaller" you mean the wall of the building, then, in order to keep the area the same, we wouldn't be able to reach over the $10$ foot wall anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the ladder makes an angle $x$ with the horizontal.

Length of ladder $ = 4\sec x + 10\csc x $

Area of triangle = $8\tan x + 50(\tan x)^{-1} + 40 $

If you minimize both by differentiating and setting to zero, you get different conditions. Hence they are not equivalent.

Comment: Would you explain how you got those formulas?

Comment: It's SOHCAHTOA, but realize that there are similar triangles, so $\theta$ appears twice, in one triangle where the ladder meets the ground and at the top of the wall where the ladder continues to the building

Comment: I found the length of hypotenuse and both the sides using trigonometric relations.